# Force IE use compatibility mode Specific page

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I use following tag(in web.config) to force IE use latest version compability mode.

```
 <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=edge" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
```

now I want force only one page of my solution work with IE7 comparability mode.
is that possible?

note:

I put `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />` in that page but it not work.

Comment: did you try using HttpModule and check request url then remove the header?

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways is that you can use HttpModule and handle your business specifically for this requested url in EndRequest Event ex

[image]

[image]

For more details you can check https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/63e78b/remove-unwanted-http-headers-in-Asp-Net/